# package-lock.json resolution urls are incorrect

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I have scoped dependencies and npm is configured such that it finds those packages at our private repo:

```
@kw:registry=https://slug.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/npm/main/
//slug.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/npm/main/:_auth=***
//slug.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/npm/main/:email=***
//slug.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/npm/main/:always-auth=true
registry=https://registry.npmjs.com/
```

However, in my `package-lock.json` there remains hundreds of public packages with `resolved` url values of my private repo, not `npmjs.org`:

```
},
    "@babel/runtime": {
      "version": "7.20.0",
      "resolved": "https://slug.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/npm/main/@babel/runtime/-/runtime-7.20.0.tgz",
```

We previously had all dependencies (scoped and not scoped) resolving to our private repository which proxied requests to `npmjs.org`. Since defining our scope and configuring it in `.npmrc` I would expect unscoped packages resolve to the default of `npmjs.org`.

I'm on an older version of npm, 6.14.15. I've tried purging the lock file and rebuilding with `npm i`.

Is there a way to change npm 6 behavior so that urls in `package-lock.json` resolve or default to the public npm registry?